# reading a file and getting each line of the file separately

Tags: python

I have a text file which has three lines.
I want to read those three lines as
L1, L2 and L3 and count the character
of L1, L2 and L3 as n1, n2 and n3. I tried as
follows:

```
     f=open(sys.argv[1],'r')
     L1=f.readline()   
     L2=f.readline()   
     L3=f.readline()  
     if L1[-1]=='\n': L1=L1[:len(L1)-1] 
     if L2[-1]=='\n': L2=L2[:len(L2)-1] 
     if L3[-1]=='\n': L3=L3[:len(L3)-1] 
     n1=len(L1); n2=len(L2); n3=len(L3) 
     print L1, n1, L2, n2, L3, n3
```

The above script is working fine. But I wanted to know if there is a better/easier
way to get L1, L2 and L3. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
  L1, L2, L3 = (line.rstrip() for line in f.readlines()[:3])
```

But you should really use lists...

Answer (score 1):

You could:

- Add exception handling using try-catch IOError for any problem opening the file and reading from it. See [Errors and Exceptions Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) - or use the `with` statement for newer versions of Python as suggested by other answers.
- Add exception handling using try-catch IndexError to handle the case where not enough arguments are given.
- Do the check for newline with string.rstrip or string.strip for brevity.
- Store the values in an array  as suggested by other answers (you might want to terminate after 3 lines in case you get the wrong file and end up reading a very large file into memory).

Answer (score 0):

The best way in my opinion is try putting them in an array. I dont use python but thats what ill do in c++

Answer (score 0):

sure..

```
lines = []
with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        if line[-1] == "\n":
            line = line[:-1]
        lines.append(line)
```

This way it doesn't matter how many lines you have in your file. Your program will still run until the end

Answer (score 0):

I searched in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/python-read-file-line-by-line-into-array) and found a code that is simpler.
It saves the content into an array:

```
with open(fname) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
```

If you want to strip the \n:

```
with open(fname) as f:
    content = [line.strip() for line in f]
```